# Can you attack multiple targets when you have a rate of fire greater than 1?

Tags: adnd-1e, ranged-attack, osric

I'm DMing a campaign with OSRIC as the base rules and 1e AD&D as secondary rules where needed.  One of our characters is using a bow that the rules say has a rate of fire of 2.  I'm looking for a published rule that clarifies whether or not the character must attack the same target with both shots.  I've not been able to find it in the Gygax PHB, DMG, or OSRIC 2nd Edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've not been able to find such a rule because there is no restriction. Having multiple attacks allows you to use them against multiple targets.

Comment: Does that mean that rate of fire of two should be viewed as multiple attacks per round in the same sense as a fighter gaining multiple attacks at higher levels?  If that is the case, maybe I should move the second arrow to the end of the round like you would with a fighter's second attack.

Comment: That's exactly how it works, yes. The rules for timing multiple attacks by PCs apply to all ways of having multiple attacks, barring rules or rulings that make exceptions. (e.g., the rule that allows claw/claw/bite to be all at once; or a DM ruling that a handful of shuriken may be thrown all at once instead of sequentially.)

Comment: Or you could assign a penalty to the to-hit roll. I tend to eyeball the proposed target and if it's within a certain range, say 20' or so, I'll allow it, but if it's waaaaaaay across the battlefield, at lower levels, I might assign a -2 to hit.